# How to catch an exception and throw a different exception

Tags: scala, exception

I have a for loop that I'm expecting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on. I want this particular exception, when raised, to throw a custom exception. I currently have this:

```
try {
  for (i <- 0 until end) {
    // do something
  }
} catch {
  case e: IndexOutOfBoundsException =>
    throw CustomException("Raised expected IndexOutOfBoundsException", e)
}
```

However, when the above snippet is run, the compiler tells me that an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` was raised and *not* my custom exception. What would I have to do to raise my custom exception?

The custom exception is defined as:

```
case class CustomException(private val message: String = "", private val cause: Throwable = None.orNull) extends Exception(message, cause)
```

Comment: Can you post the exception you get from the compiler? I get a `CusomException` using this.

Comment: @Shaido I'm getting the IndexOutOfBounds Exception and not the custom exception.

Comment: Does the program go into the `catch` part of the code at all? Try debugging/printing something to see if that is the case or not. The only thing I can think of is that usually it's `throw new CustomException`, with the `new` keyword, but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: @Shaido I think the issue actually has to do with error propagation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Try` and `recoverWith`. `recoverWith` handles the failure case and further tries to propagate the success or failure of new Try computation.

```
Try {
  for (i <- 0 until end) {
    // do something
  }
}.recoverWith { case e: IndexOutOfBoundsException =>
 Try.failed(CustomException("Raised expected IndexOutOfBoundsException", e))
}
```